# Angular Material 2 data table sorting arrow in header

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm playing around with Angular Material 2 data table with sorting.

For some tables the sorting arrow in the table header has strange behavior. It's looking like "T", look at the image bellow. Any ideas what that means ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems like a bug https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7291
It could be patched with lazy loading of the component until they fixed it.